# Method of Images in Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

What's the use of the method of images in electrostatics? I have absolutely no idea about its applications and the problems in which I should apply it.
I would request someone to not only explain its importance but also give an example in the form of a problem (if possible) in order to clarify the concept to the fullest extent.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general electrostatic problem can be stated as follows:

Every where outside the conductor, $\phi$ has to satisfy the partial differential equation
$$\nabla^2\phi=0$$
with appropriate boundarary conditions which can be set of $\phi_k$ on each conductors or charge.

---

The method of image is way to solve this problem using the so fact of uniqueness of the solution.
The situation was well described by Maxwell:

> “It appears, therefore, that what we should naturally call the inverse problem of determining the forms of the conductors when the expression for
> the potential is given is more manageable than the direct problem of determining the potential when the form of the conductors is given."

More on this can be found on : Electricity and Magnetism : Purcell Section 3.4